# Python and Ghostscript: OSError: Too many open files

Tags: windows, ghostscript

I'm running ghostscript via python 2.7 on Windows to convert a bunch of 1 page PDF files to TIFF images.

```
from os import listdir, remove
from os.path import isfile, join
import ghostscript
import os
import time
import sys

#Assumption #1: The input folder, output_tif_folder and output_pdf_folder
#Assumption #2: Paths in windows use a backslash for reference. They have to be escaped characters - so use a \\ instead of a single \
#   eg: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\'
#Assumption #3: Required libraries are configured and installed properly. They are - i) ghostscript and ii) pyPdf

input_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\test_files\\'; #Has to be the absolute path, ending with a slash
output_pdf_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\pdf\\'; #Has to be an absolute path too, ending with a slash
output_tif_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\tif\\' #Absolute path too, ending with a slash

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(input_folder) if isfile(join(input_folder, f))]

from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

for pdfFile in onlyfiles:
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(input_folder + pdfFile, 'rb'))
    for i in xrange(inputpdf.numPages):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
        with open(output_pdf_folder + pdfFile[:-4] + "_%s.pdf" % (i+1), "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)

def convertPdfTiff(inputfilename, outputfilename):
    args = [
    "pdf2tif", # actual value doesn't matter
    "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER",
    "-sDEVICE=tiff24nc",
    "-sCompression=pack",
    "-sOutputFile=" + outputfilename,
    "-f",  inputfilename
    ]
    try:
        ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
    except:
        print 'something went wrong'

pagefiles = [f for f in listdir(output_pdf_folder) if isfile(join(output_pdf_folder, f))]
for pagefile in pagefiles:
    print 'Input: ' + output_pdf_folder + pagefile
    print 'Output: ' + output_tif_folder + pagefile[:-4] + ".tif"
    convertPdfTiff(output_pdf_folder + pagefile, output_tif_folder + pagefile[:-4] + ".tif")
    time.sleep(1)
```

After converting around 114 files, I get the following error -
`OSError: Too many open files`

Other posts on similar issues suggest that file descriptors should be closed gracefully, but since I'm not opening them (I'm assuming ghostscript does that), I can't close them.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python developer, but it seems to me that you are opening files (apologies if I'm incorrect):

```
for pdfFile in onlyfiles:
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(input_folder + pdfFile, 'rb'))
```

I'm not seeing where you close those files. Other than that, Ghostscript certainly should be closing all its own files, though I have seen Windows take some time to actually close files after GS has disposed of them. You could try putting a longer time.sleep() in there to see if that helps.

Its certainly possible to execute this from the command line (ie using Ghostscript directly instead of using the DLL as you seem to be) and process hundreds of files. Since the Ghostscript executable uses the same DLL there shouldn't be a problem using it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has probably already being solved but here is for someone who might come across this page.

You open files with

```
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(input_folder + pdfFile, 'rb'))
```

line but you never close these files, like KenS stated. To fix this, use `with`-statement like you have done later on the second `for`-loop.

```
for pdfFile in onlyfiles:
    with open(input_folder + pdfFile, 'rb') as inputpdf:
        reader = PdfFileReader(inputpdf)
        for i in xrange(reader.numPages):
            output = PdfFileWriter()
            output.addPage(reader.getPage(i))
            with open(output_pdf_folder + pdfFile[:-4] + "_%s.pdf" % (i+1), "wb") as outputStream:
                output.write(outputStream)
```

This way both inputpdf and outputStream get closed no matter what, because that is how `with`-statement works. Even you get exception inside `with`-statement, the file will be closed.

Copied from here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement:

> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager (see section With Statement
>   Context Managers). This allows common `try…except…finally` usage
>   patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.
>
> ```
> with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
> with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
> ```
>
> The execution of the with statement with one “item” proceeds as
>   follows:
>
> 1. The context expression (the expression given in the with_item) is evaluated to obtain a context manager.
> 2. The context manager’s `__exit__()` is loaded for later use.
> 3. The context manager’s `__enter__()` method is invoked.
> 4. If a target was included in the with statement, the return value from `__enter__()` is assigned to it.
>
> **Note:**
>
> ***The with statement guarantees that if the `__enter__()` method returns without an error, then `__exit__()` will always be called.
>   Thus, if an error occurs during the assignment to the target list, it
>   will be treated the same as an error occurring within the suite would
>   be. See step 6 below.***
>
> 5. The suite is executed.
> 6. The context manager’s `__exit__()` method is invoked. If an exception caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and
>      traceback are passed as arguments to `__exit__()`. Otherwise, three
>      `None` arguments are supplied.
>
> If the suite was exited due to an exception, and the return value from
>   the `__exit__()` method was false, the exception is reraised. If the
>   return value was true, the exception is suppressed, and execution
>   continues with the statement following the with statement.
>
> If the suite was exited for any reason other than an exception, the
>   return value from `__exit__()` is ignored, and execution proceeds at
>   the normal location for the kind of exit that was taken.